# Facebook Like button not registering my like

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins

Is anyone experiencing what I'm experiencing when you go to http://aentan.com/design/more-natural-design-comps/ and click on the Facebook Like button. When I click on it, it changes to "1 person" and then the comment field appears but after half a second it goes back to the original like button like it did not register my click.

I'm using the social plugin on my WordPress single.php template and all the Like buttons on other pages work.

If I remove the open graph meta tags the Like button works.

`<meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(); ?>">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">`

What's wrong?

Comment: Edited. now I know if I remove the open graph meta tags the like button works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can either fill the required Open Graph tags or not using them at all (which is not recommended):

If you use Open Graph tags, the following six are required:

- og:title - The title of the entity.
- og:type - The type of entity. You must select a type from the list of Open Graph types.
- og:image - The URL to an image that represents the entity. Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall.
- og:url - The canonical, permanent URL of the page representing the entity. When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.
- og:site_name - A human-readable name for your site, e.g., "IMDb".
- fb:admins or fb:app_id - A comma-separated list of either the Facebook IDs of page administrators or a Facebook Platform application ID. At a minimum, include only your own Facebook ID.

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me also. Check out [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) really useful facebook tool. It helped to solve my problem.